# Loss function Keras out_dim > 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I have a training data:

[image]

And, I have a model in Keras with more than one dimension of output. I want to predict A, B and C:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(32, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

But I want the minimum `mean_squared_error` in A, i.e. only want to consider A for the loss function.

What I can do?

Comment: What are your inputs? It looks like you are trying to predict the variables based on the variables themselves (in which case the identity will do fine).

Comment: So are you using A, B and C to predict A, B and C .?

Comment: @SreeramTP, Yes, I want  predict A, B and C for 2019, 2020, ...

Comment: @fuglede, Yes I predict A, B and C based In the previous data of A, B and C, but I want that the loss function performance the error of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom loss function and only compute the `mean_squared_error()` loss based on the value of `A`:

```
from keras import losses

def loss_A(y_true, y_pred):
    return losses.mean_squared_error(y_true[:,0], y_pred[:,0])

#...
model.compile(loss=loss_A, optimizer='adam')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to look into is a custom loss function:

```
def only_A_mean_squared(y_true, y_pred):
     return keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true[:,0], y_pred[:,0])
```

And in order to use it:

```
model.compile(loss=only_A_mean_squared, optimizer='adam')
```

What i am doing in the above is creating a custom loss function, which only takes the first dimension (the 'A') and feed it to the normal keras mean squared error loss function.